# Where is the datavisulizer lib for silverlight/wp7?

Tags: visual-studio, silverlight, windows-phone-7

Im trying to get started with silverlight for wp7 and I understand its Silverlight 4 that is the current version running on the WP7. So i installed [Silverlight 4](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=177428) and then installed the latest (?) toolkit for [Silverlight for Wp7 (November 2011)](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/releases/view/75888) but I cant seem to find the datavisualizer required to make charts in the following directories:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Phone\v7.1\Toolkit\Oct11\Bin
```

(i know it stands Oct11, but thats what i got when I installed it)

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Phone\v7.1\Libraries\Silverlight
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Silverlight\v4.0\Libraries\Client
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Silverlight\4.0.50826.0
```

What do I need to install to get the `System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Toolkit.dll`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The datavisualization library is only references in the full Silverlight toolkit and not in the Windows Phone one.

It seems like you're trying to use the Silverlight 4 toolkit in a Windows Phone app. This is not supported.

Windows Phone 7.1 is based on Silverlight 4 but it does not support all the features of Silverlight 4.

The charts controls are not supported in the Windows Phone version of the toolkit.

If you're looking for a charting solution for Windows Phone you'll have to look elsewhere. I know the solutions from [amCharts](http://wpf.amcharts.com/download), [Telerik](http://www.telerik.com/products/windows-phone/chart.aspx), [visiblox](http://www.visiblox.com/) and [Mindscape](http://www.mindscapehq.com/blog/index.php/2011/03/03/mindscape-phone-elements-released/) are popular but there are probably others out there also.